# Extract Outlook email body into CSV

Tags: python, pandas, outlook, pywin32, office-automation

Hello I receive this email daily and trying to automate this task.

Here is an example of the email body, I'm not sure what's the format of it.

Email body:

[image: Email Body].

My goal here is to get all the rows into a CSV file. Then I can split the text but I'm not sure how to turn it into a CSV.

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Automation")
Mail_Messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = mail.Body
print(body_content)
```

Also here is the current output I'm getting. Would it be possible to ignore the External Email warning?

[image: Current Output]

Answer (score 0):

You can use string functions to get a substring which starts after the `chrexternaltag` substring. For example, in Python you could use the [Split](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) function.